# Get percentage difference of each item's price by comparing them with the average value of a field

Tags: mysql, sql

How would you get the average price in each category, compare it against each item of that category and get the percentage difference?

For example,in the table below, the average price of a doll is 24, so item B ($18) should be **-25%**, which is cheaper than the average of the category. ((18-24) / 24) * 100).

How can I join these two queries and then do the calculation?

```
SELECT price from `product` GROUP BY name

SELECT AVG(price) AS average_Price from `product` GROUP BY category

(price - AVG(price))/AVG(price)*100
```

Table Example:

```
ID  name    category      price  
1     A     Puzzle          5
2     B     Doll            18
3     C     Puzzle          10
4     D     Outdoor         20
5     E     Brainteaser     2
6     F     Outdoor         40
7     G     Doll            30
8     H     Brainteaser     9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so ,use a self join with a subquery ,this subquery will get the average price for each category and then in select part perform your calculation

```
select t.*,tt.avg_price 
,((t.price - tt.avg_price ) / tt.avg_price *100) precent_diff
from 
t
join (select category ,avg(price) avg_price from t group by category) tt
on(t.category = tt.category)
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81f0af/4)

To have percent sign use concat with end result of calculation part

```
select t.*,tt.avg_price 
,
concat(
((t.price - tt.avg_price ) / tt.avg_price *100)
  ,'%')
  precent_diff
from 
t
join (select category ,avg(price) avg_price from t group by category) tt
on(t.category = tt.category)
```

### [Demo with sign](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81f0af/5)

Answer (score 1):

Have an inner query to get AVG per category and then use a `JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT name, product.category, price, ((price - avg_price)/avg_price)*100 as diff
FROM product
JOIN (
  SELECT category, AVG(price) as avg_price
  FROM product
  GROUP BY category
) t
ON t.category = product.category
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f25205/5

Answer (score 1):

with a nested query:

```
select a.name, a.category, (price-avg_price)/avg_price*100 ratio
from product a
join (
  select category, avg(price) avg_price
  from product a
  group by a.category) b on a.category = b.category;
```